# How can we set up a Docker mirror for a private cluster?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to set up a private cluster in the Google Kubernetes Engine, and as the nodes don't have access to the public internet, they cannot pull from Docker Hub.

As described [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters#docker_hub), the resolution is to configure the Docker daemon to fetch also from Google's internal mirror, but I have not found an option to do so when setting the cluster, and as the nodes are private, I don't expect to have access to do that manually.

What is the best way (if any) to configure the nodes to enable that?

Comment: Private cluster by default do not have access to public internet and it is not possible to configure your Docker daemon to fetch images from Container Registry's Docker Hub mirror while creating cluster. You can use either CLI or Docker UI, are the best way to [configure Docker daemon](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/using-dockerhub-mirroring#fetch_images_froms_mirror). Would you please clarify what you meant by you don't have access to your node to do these step manually? Did you try the CLI/Docker UI to configure Docker daemon? Are you getting any error?

Comment: With manually I mean precisely entering the nodes and configuring the Docker daemon with the CLI. As it is in a private network I preferably would like to avoid special network configs to achieve that.

So far the best option I have found is to configure a NAT gateway and let the cluster make use of it to access the public internet, but it was feeling natural to have some way of configuring the node pools also to configure the Docker repos to pull from (either public or other possible privates). Is entering the nodes and configuring them the only way?

Comment: As far as I am aware of, [configuring Docker daemon](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/using-dockerhub-mirroring#fetch_images_froms_mirror) is the only option.

Answer (score -1):

Private cluster by default do not have access to public internet and it is not possible to configure your Docker daemon to fetch images from Container Registry's Docker Hub mirror while creating cluster. You can use either CLI or Docker UI, are the best way to [configure Docker daemon](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/using-dockerhub-mirroring#fetch_images_froms_mirror).

As far as I am aware of, configuring Docker daemon is the only option.